# Merge overlapping points in the same layer by maintaining both attbributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, point

I have a road network layer where each line segment is broken off by intersecting line features. I ran the intersect tool to create points along each line intersect to represent 'Intersection' point layer. Now, I have 2 points for every intersect which includes data from both intersecting lines (street names). I want to have one point for every intersect that includes the street names from both lines.

I have tried to Delete Identical, which works, but it removes on random point. I don't know how to merge these overlapping points in the same layer to a new layer that has street name from both overlapping points?

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood the question correctly, the Dissolve Tool will also give you the results you want.

In the point layer you created using the intersect, create 3 fields.
X (Double), Y (Double) and Comb(String / Text).

Populate the X and Y fields with the associated coordinates for that point.
In the Comb field, combine the X and the Y fields using:

```
X & Y
```

In the field calculator. This will give you a result which looks like a mess, but each of these points should have exactly the same reference now, and there should not be any duplicates.

Run the Dissolve Tool using the Comb field as the Dissolve Field.
Under "Statistics" Choose the fields you want to have moved into a single row. Under Statistics Type, choose FIRST.

The dissolve will run and the output will be a single row per point, with the First value in the fields you were interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how close each points are you could probably just do a spatial join and select the retain all attributes option. Right-click layer > join > join data from another layer based on spatial location [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have run into something similar before. I don't know what your tables look like but what we had was a unique attribute for each pair of points.

We then added a field and populated it incrementally, 1+. Next we did select by attributes and queried only even numbers on that field (in our case this meant the odd number was the first feature and the even was the duplicate [in all pairs]). We exported that table, then deleted those selected records from the initial layer. Next we joined the exported table based on the unique ID (shared between the pairs) and exported to a new layer. This may be a long way of doing it, plus add a little field cleanup, but it was quick in our case and worked.

Highly recommend creating a backup of your initial layer before using this method.